# COVID bike build 2020 first timer

Tags: road-bike, build

I am building my first road bike. I have been an avid biker rider for quite sometime and always thought about getting a road bike, just never got around to it.

Fast forward to now, my neighbor (pro rider) threw his Scott CR1 carbon fiber frame in the dumpster along with a MOST carbon handlebar and Cosmic wheel set.  Now that I acquired all this stuff for free, time to finally build a bike!

My point of this post is first to get some advice on ... where to start? How do I find out what is compatible to this bike from a component group, to putting everything together etc.

I know I won't be able to do everything but I know I can get pretty far then I am planning on taking it to a local guy to do a tuneup before I get her out on the road.

I want to build as tough and reliable as possible on a budget (don't want to spend a ton but want a quality bike). Let me know if anyone can help out with where to get started, also if you have parts for sale or anything or want to trade for something, I am wide open to that as well. Picture is attached, let me know what year as well if anyone knows.

Thanks David

[image]

Comment: Did you verify with your neighbor the frame is sound and he's not reading it because it's busted?

Comment: Maybe you could use it on a hometrainer if not safe for road.

Comment: Put any tyre on the rear wheel to protect it in the short term.  Anything to stop the bare rim touching the floor.

Comment: I went through the whole thing looking for cracks and didnt see anything.

Comment: @DeanoTheKId heya - its been three years, how did you get on with this build?   What did you change and what would you have liked to know beforehand ?

Answer (score 5):

Before you commit to putting money and effort into a build ask yourself *is this really the bike you want?* Doing your own bike build can be fun and fulfilling but you want to end up with a bike you actually want and will enjoy riding

Is the frame actually the right size for you. You obviously can't sit on it do try it out in its current condition. What size is it and how tall are you? How tall is your neighbor? Look on Scott's web site for size guidance perhaps. Is the cockpit geometry right for you? The CR1 probably has a fairly aggressive low handlebar position. I note that the steerer is cut so you cannot raise the stem. What I would do in your position is measure the CR1's stack and reach geometry, then compare that with some other road bikes that you can test ride at local bike stores. That's not really an option during the current situation.

You also need to address safety issues. If the bike was owned by a pro it probably has done a lot of miles. There may be a reason it ended up in the trash (carbon is cracked) or perhaps your neighbor is getting a new bike for free or for a good deal an could not be bothered to sell this frame and get a couple of hundred bucks (if that) for it. Check the frame and fork carefully all over for signs of damage, impacts, paint cracks etc. Same for the seatpost, stem, handlebar. Take the fork out and inspect the steerer tube as well.

Check the wheels are true, check spoke tension by pinching pairs of spokes together - you are looking for ones that are loose. Check the wear on the brake track (there should be a wear indicator groove. Check the rims for dings or scrapes.

if the bike has lot of miles the the bearings may be worn out. Turn the bars and check for play, excessive friction, roughness or 'notchiness', do the same with the wheel axles. Put a finger in the BB bearings and turn them them looking for the same issues.

Next step is to do your homework and start learning all about bike components and compatibility and how to install everything properly and all the tools you'll need. There are lots of resources online that are not hard to find with Google. My personal favourite is [Park Tool](https://www.parktool.com) which as has tons of great repair articles and videos. You should be able to find some full bike build up videos on YouTube which will get you started. If you have a particular problem or issue look for existing questions with answers on this site. Be aware that in component installation and adjustment details are *really important*. Do stuff right, don't take shortcuts.

The good news is that road bikes are pretty standardized. A Shimano rim brake groupset will probably bolt right on. There are only a few options to deal with such as the front derailleur mount type and the bottom bracket type.

There are many online bike component stores the are easy to find via Google. I'd go with a bike specific store rather than Amazon etc. as you get better guidance and access to specs and data. Ebay is great for used parts but you do have to know what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you @argenti Apparatus

Answer (score 4):

1. This frame is about 10 years old (the model was sold for a few years). There is a chance that there's a crack in the carbon fiber, which would be cause for concern. There are services that will perform non-destructive testing, and there are ways to perform inspections at home with somewhat less reliability, but that would be my first concern.
2. It looks like the bottom bracket is intact. If the bearings turn smoothly, keep them. If not, you'll want to replace them, which would probably be the most complex part of your build. It looks like this bike takes a PF86 bottom bracket (there are [numerous standards](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/the-complete-guide-to-bottom-bracket-standards/)).
3. This bike was sold with a Shimano 105 group (possibly other groups as well). 105 has good performance and good value, so you won't go wrong with that. You'll obviously need caliper brakes, not disk, but that's about the only requirement from the options that will be available to you.
4. It looks like it has a front derailleur braze-on, so you'll need to make sure you get a compatible derailleur.
5. There are a lot of other options that will be matters of personal taste. Crankarm length, chainring tooth counts, cassette tooth counts, saddle, pedals, bar tape color, etc.
6. This is not a marketplace or swap meet, so not a good place to find the parts you'll need.

Comment: I checked through the entire frame and don't see any showing of cracks or anything.

Comment: Looks like an external threaded BB to me

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus What do you mean by external threaded BB?  Sorry I am a rookie!

Comment: @DeanoTheKId welcome to the process of learning all about bike components and compatibility! Start here https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-identification. Also, of you put a close up pic of the BB area in you question someone will tell you want type it is.

Comment: @DeanoTheKId checking through the entire frame and not seeing any crack does not exclude that the cracks are on the internal side of the frame. By your own evaluation, you are not an expert: maybe your neighbour felt the bike was "softer" than it was before. Therefore deciding "it is going to crack soon" and throwing it away. Or maybe he had an accident/collision and don't trust anymore the frame (a bit like helmets, safety dictates to change them after a crash)

Answer (score 3):

There's a great resource that will help with how to do this.
https://www.sheldonbrown.com/

Sadly, Sheldon passed a short while back, but this comprehensive site is his legacy. If you can't find the info on there, you're not trying ;-)

The bike looks to be a 56/58cm so would probably be fine for a first road bike as long as you're taller than 178cm/5'10"

99% sure this is a Scott CR1 2007.

That bottom bracket is going to be 68mm wide. If the hole in the middle is 24mm it will take a shimano or Campagnolo chainset. If it's 30mm it's had a sram groupset on it, but that's pretty unlikely

There are massive sales on group sets with rim brakes at the moment. Look at Rival from SRAM, 105 from shimano or Potenza from Campagnolo if you want something a little flash.

buy the entire groupset rather than bit by bit.  It's a bigger once off hit to the wallet, but everything will be included to do the job and will work together. Merlin cycles, or wiggle/Chain reaction cycles, but you probably knew that;-)

Lot of people love Continental tyres, but I can't live without my Schwalbe pro one tyres.
Again, you'll find lots on sale at the moment.

Don't get direct mount brakes, they won't fit. But otherwise, it's just going to take a stock standard groupset.

I've gotta say, I'd do this though:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33019603185.html

Matching bar stem and seatpost really finishes of a bike.
... And I'd put odds on that bar not being a genuine most unless it's stickered and labeled as such, it looks Chinese, but i could certainly be wrong.

If the bottom bracket bearing moves smoothly and easily without much play, just put some grease on it and it will be fine for at least a few thousand kms.  If it doesn't, look up the frame on the interwebs, and buy a new bottom bracket that will fit the groupset you've chosen. It will 99% likely be an English bb.

If there is damage to the frame it will be instantly identifiable. It may have a few scratches, but you'll feel a crack that's unsafe as it won't be smooth to run your hands over. Twist the frame in your hands and it shouldn't flex at all. Rear triangle should only deflect a few millimetres when you push the dropouts towards each other firmly (no need to try to crush it) Carbon is a lot stronger and more durable than people think and Scott will have used quality epoxy that will fail gracefully rather than just collapse, it's a safety thing. If it's damaged badly it's going to be very obvious.

MUST!!!
Buy a cheap 5nm torque wrench ($30-$50) and use carbon paste where carbon holds carbon!

Comment: Noshy thanks for the information, I have been researching component sets and that seems like the easiest way to do it.    I think I figured out why this guy threw this bike away, looks like the bottom bracket is pretty well stuck in there and I have to try to figure out how to get it out, then I can start prepping for when I buy the component set.   The SHimano 105 is that a high end set or mid?  If I buy, I want to buy once and with my current two bikes that I ride one has a shitty set and one is great and smooth, so I want to buy quality.

Comment: That could be the problem.  Being a threaded bottom bracket, if it wasn't greased when assembled its simply never going to come out.  You'd have to take the bearings out hacksaw down to the thread in a few places (DON'T SAW INTO THE THREAD) and then hit it with a chisel.  You shouldn't have to hit it too hard as it is aluminium.

Comment: It's a bit risky and take care, but if the bottom bracket is done then there's no other option.  Good luck!!!.  A 105 groupset is a very good quality groupset and will serve you well and be fast  for many years. Shimano generally take their dura ace grouppo and make most of it 105 when they release their new dura ace version.